# F# Binary Search Tree

Tags: f#, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement BST in F#. Since I am starting my journey with F# I wanted to ask for help.

I have simple a test;

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Data is retained`` () =
    let treeData = create [4]
    treeData |> data |> should equal 4
    treeData |> left |> should equal None
    treeData |> right |> should equal None
```

Tree type which uses discriminated unions

```
type Tree<'T> =
    | Leaf
    | Node of value: 'T * left: Tree<'T> * right: Tree<'T>
```

a recursive function which inserts data nodes into the tree

```
let rec insert newValue (targetTree: Tree<'T>) =
    match targetTree with
    | Leaf -> Node(newValue, Leaf, Leaf)
    | Node (value, left, right) when newValue < value ->
        let left' = insert newValue left
        Node(value, left', right)
    | Node (value, left, right) when newValue > value -> 
        let right' = insert newValue right
        Node(value, left, right')
    | _ -> targetTree
```

now I have problems with create function. I have this:

```
let create items = 
    List.fold insert Leaf items
```

and resulting error:

> FS0001    Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       ''a -> Tree<'a> -> 'a'     but given a
>       ''a -> Tree<'a> -> Tree<'a>'     The types ''a' and 'Tree<'a>' cannot be unified.

Comment: try to switch argument order in `insert` function.
`let rec insert targetTree newValue`

Comment: @Szer - I don't recommend switching the argument order in `insert`: it's actually the *right* order already for use with the `|>` operator, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`List.fold` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5B't%2C'state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) shows its type signature as:

```
List.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State
```

Let's unpack that. The first argument is a function of type `'State -> 'T -> 'State`. That means it takes a state and an argument of type T, and returns a new state. Here, the state is your `Tree` type: starting at a basic `Leaf`, you're building up the tree step by step. Second argument to `List.fold` is the initial state (a `Leaf` in this case), and third argument is the list of items of type T to fold over.

Your second and third arguments are correct, but your first argument doesn't line up with the signature that `List.fold` is expecting. `List.fold` wants something of type `'State -> 'T -> 'State`, which in your case would be `Tree<'a> -> 'a -> Tree<'a>`. That is, a function that takes the tree as its *first* parameter and a single item as its *second* parameter. But your `insert` function takes the parameters the other way around (the item as the first parameter, and the tree as the second parameter).

I'll pause here to note that your `insert` function is **correct** according to the style rules of idiomatic F#, and you *should not* change the order of its parameters. When writing functions that deal with collections, you always want to take the collection as the last parameter so that you can write something like `tree |> insert 5`. So I strongly suggest you don't change the order of the arguments your `insert` function takes.

So if you shouldn't change the order of arguments of your `insert` function, yet they're in the wrong order to use with `List.fold`, what do you do? Simple: you create an anonymous function with the arguments flipped around, so that you can use `insert` with `List.fold`:

```
let create items = 
    List.fold (fun tree item -> insert item tree) Leaf items
```

Now we'll go one step further and generalize this. It's actually pretty common in F# programming to find that your two-parameter function has the parameters the right way around for most things, but the wrong way around for one particular use case. To solve that problem, sometimes it's useful to create a general-purpose function called `flip`:

```
let flip f = fun a b -> f b a
```

Then you could just write your `create` function like this:

```
let create items = 
    List.fold (flip insert) Leaf items
```

Sometimes the use of `flip` can make code *more* confusing rather than *less* confusing, so I don't recommend using it all the time. (This is also why there isn't a `flip` function in the F# standard library: because it's not always the best solution. And because it's trivial to write yourself, its lack in the standard library is not a big deal). But sometimes using `flip` makes code simpler, and I think this is one of those cases.

P.S. The `flip` function could also have been written like this:

```
let flip f a b = f b a
```

This definition is identical to the `let flip f = fun a b -> f b a` definition I used in the main example. Do you know why?

Comment: many many thanks for helping understand all of that! Regarding your question; I think that the first flip function just calls the passed function with flipped parameters. In the second case we are replacing the function. It reminds me javascript code testing where you can easily replace functions instead of writing mocks.

Comment: Good guess, but both definitions are identical. In both cases, when you call `flip insert` the result is a function which takes two parameters `a` and `b`, and then calls `insert b a`. What's going on here is called "currying", and I think the next step in your learning F# should probably be to read https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/ which explains it way better than I could in a 600-character comment. (Then read the rest of that site: it's the best site on the Internet for learning F#).